# Fetch image from azure-blob and send it to client without saving locally using node server

Tags: node.js, angular, azure-blob-storage, fastify

I want to fetch image from azure blob storage and send it over to client without saving it locally.  I am able to get image from blob storage and save it to local file but struggling to send it to client without saving locally.  Please find code below

```
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

    const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
    console.log('\nDownloaded blob content...');
    let f = await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)
    
    reply.type('image/jpg').send(f)
```

streamToString function is as follows

```
     async function streamToString(readableStream) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const chunks = [];
        readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
            chunks.push(data.toString());
        });
        readableStream.on("end", () => {
            resolve(chunks.join(""));
        });
        readableStream.on("error", reject);
     });
}
```

I get blank screen in browser when I run this code

[image]

Comment: You could try `reply.type('image/jpg').send(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)`

Comment: Could you please tell me how to show the image in the frontend?

Comment: If the front end only displays, it can be converted to base64 format, if you need to download, use stream.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue been solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch an image from azure blob storage and send it over to the client without saving it locally, the Node server sending a [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview) to the client and the client get this image from Azure storage directly would be a better solution I think. It also eases the pressure of the Node server: generate a SAS token and send it to the client is ok, no need to read data from Storage.

Try the code below to generate a SAS token:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
    var connString = "your storage connection string";
    var container ="your container name";
    var blobName = "your image name"
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService(connString);

    // Create a SAS token that expires in an hour
    // Set start time to five minutes ago to avoid clock skew.
    var startDate = new Date();
    startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() - 5);
    var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
    expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 60);
    


    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: [azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ],  //grent read permission only
            Start: startDate,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        }
    };
    
    var sasToken = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(container, blobName, sharedAccessPolicy);
    
    var response = {};

    response.image = blobService.getUrl(container,blobName,sasToken);
    
    res.send(response);
```

Result:
[image]

Client-side could use this image URL to access this image directly from storage:

[image]

Try this to convert imageURL to base64 image content so that you can save/show images directly based on their content:

```
<html>

<body>
    <img id="displayImg">
</body>


<script>

var nodeResult = {"image":"https://stantest1016.blob.core.windows.net/stantest/test.jpeg?st=2020-10-26T04%3A53%3A51Z&se=2020-10-26T05%3A53%3A51Z&sp=r&sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=ZjY3LYbgvMn%2BSr4dAEUoqidVRT4YyH1FcW1DeKlpjYo%3D"}


function getImageData(nodeResult){


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.response);
        reader.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById('displayImg').src = reader.result;
        }
  };
    
   
    
  };
  xhr.open('GET', nodeResult.image);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();

}


getImageData(nodeResult);
</script>

</html>
```

Result:

[image]

Details of  tag:
[image]

Comment: I liked the approach ou have shared.  Thanks for this.  However Images urls are mentioned in rich text editor and stored as html in database.  It is difficult to follow this approach here.  What can be possibly done here?

Comment: Hi @NirajGawande, if you want to get image content instead of an image URL in your use case, you can just download this image by image URL first on client-side and convert this image to base64 and then display this image, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @stanley this helped me to get through